# Pinning java threads to cores

Tags: python, linux, elasticsearch, jvm

The java process I'm launching is Elasticsearch and it has numerous threads that are created.
I check that using `ps HuH p <pid> |  wc -l`.
this is how I get the pid of elasticsearch:

```
ES=`jps | egrep 'Elasticsearch' | awk '{print $1}'`
```

I pinning all the threads from the given pid to a set of cores using the following python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import argparse

def task_set(pid, core):
    print "pinning all threads of pid: ", pid, " to cores: ", core
    os.system('taskset -apc '+str(core)+' ' +str(pid)+' >/dev/null')

def main(args):
    experiments = ["1B", "2B", "1B3S", "2B2S", "1S", "2S", "3S", "4S"]
    which = args.id[0]
    idx = experiments.index(which)
    PC = ["0", "0,1", "0,2,3,4", "0,1,2,3", "2", "2,3","2,3,4", "2,3,4,5"]
    task_set(args.pid[0], PC[idx])
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--pid', nargs=1, help='appid')
    parser.add_argument('--id', nargs=1, help='core')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

However, when I look at `top -H -p <pid>` and monitor the core allocation. It does not obey most of the time.
Is there something I'm missing here? Does JVM have to do something here?

Is there anyother way I can pin the threads to the cores?

Comment: No, JVM does not impact on thread affinity itself. To simplify the problem split it into separate parts: first check if `taskset` command works from the command line, and if it does, then debug python script.

Comment: I actually did that part as well, with no luck. Plus, there are multiple java threads. How do I know how many are actually the "worker" threads?

Comment: BTW, what for is `a` argument in `taskset` command? My Linux distro does not have it. Neither I see it in [`man`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset).

Comment: `-a, --all-tasks`
`              Set or retrieve the CPU affinity of all the tasks (threads) for a given PID.`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `taskset` works fine for me. Can you clarify what command you run and how you check that it does not work.

Comment: BTW, `jstack <pid>` will show you Java threads with their OS-level pids: look for `nid=0x4a53` in the stack trace. Here 0x4a53 is actual task id in hex.

Comment: @apangin: I ran a multi-threaded benchmark (memcached with four threads and used the code above to bind threads to a specific set of cores. And use top -H -p <pid> to verify if it works.

Comment: @apangin: what is 0x4a53? how will it differ from `ES`. Look above to see how `ES` is defined. And I do not find the hex digit anywhere.

Comment: Put the script aside. Just run `taskset -apc 0 <pid>` from the command line and tell what it reports.

Comment: @apangin: with just taskset it works. but don't suspect anything wrong with the script because it works for every other scenario. Besides, does it matter when I taskset elasticsearch? because if i do after the steady-state phase, it works, before it doesn't! weird. weird

Comment: It explains why the result on top doesn't update as soon as the script it launched. Elasticsearch doesn't have any cpu load until the steady-state phase. and top updates 'last used cpu' when the load.

does that make sense @apangin?

Comment: Yes, this can be the case. I would not rely on `top` to verify the process affinity. If `taskset` called without cpu list argument prints the expected bindings, I'll assume the script has succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

`taskset` will be working correctly. However, if a process is in Sleeping state, it's current CPU will not switch to the new one.

```
cat /proc/<PID>/status | grep State:
```

To workaround this you can do

```
kill -SIGSTOP <PID>
kill -SIGCONT <PID>
```

This forces the process out of sleep state and ensures the CPU switch. `top` or `htop` will then show the value correctly.